# Trying to use async declaration in react but getting error in build

Tags: javascript, async-await, html5-canvas, babeljs, html5-video

I'm trying to use the screenshot React library but getting a build error. The code (EDIT) including some contex:

```
export class ConferencePage extends React.Component {
....

async function capture() {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const video = document.createElement("video");

  try {
    const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
    video.srcObject = captureStream;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, window.width, window.height);
    const frame = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    captureStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    window.location.href = frame;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}
render(){....}
}
export default compose(
  withConnect,
  memo,
)(ConferencePage);
```

The error:

```
ERROR in ./app/containers/ConferencePage/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/watchparty/app/containers/ConferencePage/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "(" (1169:17)`
  1167 |   }
  1168 | 
> 1169 |   async function capture() {
       |                  ^
  1170 |     const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  1171 |     const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  1172 |     const video = document.createElement("video");
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: My code seems to agree with this article from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: it's odd that it flags `capture` as the unexpected token - I wonder if it's something in the preceding lines that it causing this error - Syntax errors in javascript can be tricky

Comment: Since you're using babel, please ensure you configured it with the proper parser options to support this syntax

Comment: Is this a standalone function? Could you please post an entire module (file), with the minimum code that is necessary to cause this error?

Comment: Hi @Bergi thank you for helping! I added some context to the code. Is it enough? Regarding Babel, yes I'm using it but inherited the configuration so could use a pointer to this configuration param.

Comment: I found that this definition will build and run OK: capture = async () => {

Comment: @smartblonde [No, don't do that](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)

Answer (score 0):

[In a `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#class_body_and_method_definitions), you need to use a [method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) instead of a function declaration:

```
export class ConferencePage extends React.Component {
  …
  async capture() {
    …
  }
  render() {
    …
  }
}
```

Just like in your `render` method, there is no `function` keyword.